# HttpClient can't parse "UTF-8" Content-Type

Tags: c#, httpclient

I am experiencing a known bug in the [HttpClient](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/15947). Anytime the server response contains `"UTF-8"` (including quotes), an exception is triggered:

```
The character set provided in ContentType is invalid. Cannot read content as string using an invalid character set. ---> System.ArgumentException: '"utf-8"' is not a supported encoding name.
```

Example code:

```
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://www.facebook.com");
requestMessage.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.4044.55 Safari/537.36");

HttpResponseMessage response = _client.SendAsync(requestMessage).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

What is the usual workaroud? I am using .NETFramework 4.6.1.

Comment: I can't reproducere the issue with HttpClient using .net 4.8, may be you should upgrade.

Comment: Apparently facebook returns different Content-Type if no user-agent is set. Try with User-Agent.. See updated code

Comment: In my test it returned "utf-8" in quotes. I have set the useragent. But it worked.

Comment: What the OP didn't say in question: you have to call `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` to see the exception caused by `"utf-8"`. In this case, you could workaround this by using combination of `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` and `ReadAsByteArrayAsync`.

Comment: @weichch: Actually my code doesn't use 'ReadAsStringAsync' which might be the reason it works for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To workaround the referenced issue:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, 
        "https://www.facebook.com");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);

    byte[] buf = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    string content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf);
}
```